# How to Run a Jenkins Job(Powershell command) under context of the logged in Active Directory User

Tags: windows, powershell, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-2

**Context:**

1. Created a Domain Controller with Active Directory Setup.
2. Created another Server with Jenkins-2 installed.(DNS Points correctly to the Domain Controllers)
3. Installed the Active Directory Plugin
4. Installed the Powershell Plugin
5. Created a Powershell Job, with command
   `Copy-Item -Path \\SFTPServer\Docs\file.txt $Home`

**Steps:**

1. List item Logged in to **Jenkins Server Machine** with credentials of `globomantics.local\administrator`
2. List item Started Jenkins to be available on localhost:8080
3. List item Logged in into Jenkins using credentials of `globomantics.local\someunderprivilegeduser`
4. List item Run the above created Powershell Job

**What happens:**
Powershell window appears and runs the command .. in the context of AD User `globomantics.local\administrator`

**What is required:**
Powershell command runs in the context of `globomantics.local\someunderprivilegeduser`

I understand that when we logged into jenkins using `globomantics.local\someunderprivilegeduser`, a kerberos ticket is generated on this machine. How can i use that ticket to run this powershell command?  OR if my approach is completely wrong, what else to do?

Note: let's say `globomantics.local\someunderprivilegeduser` is **NOT** allowed to read `\\SFTPServer\Docs\file.txt`, In this case the Powershell Job should fail. BUT, since the job runs in the context of `globomantics.local\administrator`, the Job runs successfully.

Comment: When you create the job, specify the `someunderprivilegeduser` credentials

Comment: That's the problem! Since the user is already logged in with his AD credentials, I should be able to run the PS command with his credentials. I don't know how to get his credentials.